# Nokia C5 Border width bug

Tags: css, border, symbian

I have found a bug with Symbian on the Nokia C5 involving border width.

Take a look at the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TnhAw/

The top and bottom borders for some reason are taking up more **width** than the box. Is there a fix for this that anyone knows of?

Here's a rough mock up of what I'm seeing in Symbian:

[image]

Comment: Nokia C5 is Symbian OS v9.3, Series 60 rel. 3.2. Series60 phones should have built-in screenshot grabber under Research&Dev -folder.

Answer (score 1):

remove `boder-width` from `div` code or adjust according to your requirment

check http://jsfiddle.net/TnhAw/1/

Comment: No I want the borders to be different on top and bottom. It's only a bug in Symbian, looks fine everywhere else

Comment: how its look in symbian can you add screenshot

Comment: Don't know how to take a screenshot of Symbian...the top and bottom borders basically overflow the box on both sides.

Comment: i mean how would we know that what you want exactly ?? i hope you undstand

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try and set each border within separate definition as well as testing it without the `margin: 20px;`.

The CSS as follows, since fiddle won't make help in this case:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    /*margin: 20px;*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    border-bottom-width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: nope same issue. I'm sure this is a bug with Symbian's rendering engine - it makes no sense.

Comment: According to this link [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#WebKit2), S60 browsers on Symbian mobile phones use the WebKit rendering engine. So I looked at your fiddle with Chrome (uses WebKit), and it looks fine..

Comment: Well, it does something else on top or something then, because it does not render anything like Chrome does.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your CSS code? I could take a look at it.

Comment: The jsfiddle is all you need to reproduce the bug